# LINQ: Get first character of each string in an array

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, string

Consider a string array shaped like this:

```
  string[] someName = new string[] { "First", "MiddleName", "LastName" };
```

The requirement is to get the first character from each element in the array.

i.e.

> FML

Previously have tried:

```
string initials = string.Concat(someName.Select(x => x[0]));
```

**Question:** What LINQ query would you write to concatenate all the name contained in the string array to give the initials?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this:

```
string shortName = new string(someName.Select(s => s[0]).ToArray());
```

or, if you suspect that any of the strings might be empty or so:

```
string shortName = new string(someName.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                                      .Select(s => s[0]).ToArray());
```

Comment: If any of the strings are empty, this will throw

Answer (score 8):

```
  string[] someName = new string[] { "First", "MiddleName", "LastName" };
  String initials = String.Join(".",someName.Select(x => x[0].ToString()).ToArray());
```

Produces

> F.M.L

Answer (score 7):

This solution accounts for empty strings as well by removing them from the output

```
var shortName = new string(
  someName
    .Where( s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    .Select(s => s[0])
    .ToArray());
```

Comment: that wont compile, you forgot ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

```
string initials = someName.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                          .Aggregate("", (xs, x) => xs + x.First());
```

Comment: Bonus points for using Aggregate instead of String.Join or a string constructor.

Comment: I dunno if thats bonus points worthy, its kind of overkill at this point :P

Comment: Overkill perhaps, but Aggregate (aka reduce of map/reduce) is a useful thing to know about LINQ.

Comment: Your creating a new string with every + operation so thats way less efficient than the above solutions.

Answer (score -3):

```
string[] someName = new string[] { "First", "MiddleName", "LastName" };

someName.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question.